# How Do I Copy An Item From One Sharepoint List To Another?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I am trying to manually move an item from one list to another.

The second list was created as a copy of the first list so it should have all the same columns.

```
ID, Title, Assignee, Due Date, Component
```

Assignee is a Person and Component is a Choice.

Currently I am using Microsoft Flow to try to do this.

The steps I have in the flow are:

- For a selected item
- Get item
- Create item
- Delete item

When I do "Create item" I am able to use Dynamic content to set Title, Due Date and Details.

However, I am not able to use Dynamic content to set Assignee or Component.

Assignee is a drop down listed as "Assignee Claims" and Component is a drop down listed as "Component Value".

There are no items to select in "Assignee Claims" and "Component Value" forces me to select a specific Component choice rather than taking the Component value from the Get item.

Is there a way to copy all fields without having to specify them all in the flow?

If not, how do I specify the Assignee and Component dynamically?

Is there a better way to move items between lists (perhaps even not using Flow)?

Comment: Are **Assignee** and **Component** multiple selection columns? I think it's doable. Can you provide a screenshot as to what you are seeing for Assignee and Component in your Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select **Enter custom value** and then the field should be available in the Dynamic content.

[image]

[image]

[image]